# Phantomjs remove class

Tags: javascript, html, phantomjs

I use pageres-cli (phantomjs) to take a screenshot from a website.

The animated stuff doesnt work while take a screenshot. I try to remove classes from HTML before rendering page. (".wow, .fadeIn, .animated ...")

I can remove elements etc, so i'm at the right point of the code, but this following specific code doesnt work.

```
page.evaluate(function (css) {      
    [...]
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("wow")).forEach(function(script) {
        script.classList.remove("wow");
    });
}, opts.css);
```

HTML:

```
    <section class="well2 well2_ins bg-secondary-rgba">
        <div class="container">
            <h3 class="text-primary center991">
                Leistungen
                <small>
                    <a href="/"><span>Alle Leistungen</span></a>
                </small>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row center991">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".1s">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Hol- und Bringservice
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".2s">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Mobiler Service
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".3s">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Ersatzwagen
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay=".4s">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Sonnenschutzfolien
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row center991">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Klimaanlagen-Service
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">
                                        Autoglasversiegelung
                                    </h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">Dichtigkeitsprüfung</h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="thumbnail-1 thumbnail3">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/270x200?text=Platzhalter Bild" alt=""/>

                                <div class="caption" data-equal-group="2">
                                    <h5 class="txt-sec">Funktionstest</h5>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary offs1" href="/">Zum Angebot<span class="triang"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: How are you verifying that it doesn't work? Have you tried to "asynchronize" the code that checks whether it "worked"?